# HTML/CSS shapes with docx4j

Tags: java, html, css, docx, docx4j

I am using the docx4j in a java app which parses HTML/CSS and exports a docx.

What I need is to make something like:

[image]

but seems like I can only make a couple of tables with docx4j. Can it read entire html css files or only basic html with no css?

Also I've been trying to use everything from flexbox, to display table, to just float ( like 15 years ago ), for making the gird layout.

I am curious if it is a dead end or it's just me and I don't know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

docx4j-ImportXHTML can read CSS.

It uses Flying Saucer to parse the XHTML: https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer

Flying Saucer uses CSS 2.1.

If you hit a limitation, the first thing to do is to see whether Flying Saucer has captured the relevant value.  If it has, then docx4j-ImportXHTML needs to handle it correctly.

Alternatively, Google to check whether FS handles flexbox etc.  I don't think ImportXHTML handles float right now.  You could add that, of course.